# Why the Broken line lays above a convex function is called chord?

Tags: geometry, terminology

At first I was not familiar with word "chord", so I looked at the dictionary but it indicated it was a musical term.
Is there any history background between musical chord and mathematical chord?(*^_^*)

Comment: traditional word for a line segment in a circle with endpoints on the boundary

Comment: I'm guessing "chord" does not come from its musical meaning (3 tones or more played together), but from it also meaning "cord" which is a rope. So probably when this word was first used they imagined a rope (cord) was tied between the two points that it connects. In any case, that's how I've always imagined it.

Comment: Both seem to be used with an h from the 16th century possibly as hypercorrections, the musical version deriving from *accord* and the geometric version from *cord*.  See https://www.etymonline.com/word/chord

Comment: @Henry You could post an expanded version of that as an answer.